# Adjust array format after converting from XML

Tags: php, xml

I try to parse xml into arrays. I have got 2 types of incoming data:
1)

```
<rows>
<item>
<a>A</a>
<b>B</b>
</item>
<item>
<c>C</c>
<d>D</d>
</item>
</rows>
```

2)

```
<rows>
<item>
<e>E</e>
<f>F</f>
</item>
</rows>
```

I create an object of SimpleXMLElement and then convert it in array as in [Converting a SimpleXML Object to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167279/converting-a-simplexml-object-to-an-array) using first answer. The result in first case is

```
[ '0' => ['a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B'], '1' => ['c' => 'C', 'd' => 'D']].
```

The result in second case is `['e' => 'E', 'f' => 'F']`

But I need a numeric key in second case `[ '0' => ['e' => 'E', 'f' => 'F']]`

How to fix it?

Comment: You will have to handle this progrmmatically

Comment: [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19183521/14673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given example, I think you could use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) which (from the docs):

> returns all the values from the array and indexes the array
>   numerically.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$result = array_values(json_decode(json_encode($xml), true));
var_dump($result);
```

Will give you:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["e"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["f"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FtAcV)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your e,f array (Which is the output of your second case, but i've generated it here. Just use your XML array from your second case)

```
$arr1 = array(
    'e' => 'E',
    'f' => 'F',
    'g' => 'G',
    'h' => 'H',
);
```

you can then do

```
$arr2 = array_chunk($arr1, 2);
```

which will give you the output ($arr2):

```
[0 => ['e' => 'E', 'f' => 'F'], 1=> ['g' => 'G', 'h' => 'H']]
```

and that will work assuming that you want your sub arrays to always be 2 items in length. You can change that by changing the second parameter of array_chunk().

Comment: Not sure if this answers OP's question at all.

Comment: They wanted the output of the array to be split into seperate numerically keyed arrays, this does that, but I might have misunderstood the question.